# Launching another Applet from another Applet

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I have made a Loader Applet which greets the user and when user clicks the button displayed on that Applet it then launches the main applet and the Loader Applet is destroyed.

But on clicking Another applet is not launched !

**Loader Applet:**

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Loader extends JApplet implements ActionListener{
    Display secondApplet;
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(800,600);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button = new Button ("Click me !!");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        secondApplet = (Display)getAppletContext().getApplet("Display");
        if (secondApplet != null) {
            secondApplet.init();
            secondApplet.start();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not Running\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Display Applet:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Display extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(600,400);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }
}
```

**How can I create an instance of the other Applet and destroy the current Applet !!**

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Actually I was getting NullPointerException !!
So I tried putting a If-else Clause and got the output "Not Running"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an Applet/JApple is a **java.awt.Panel** itself, then you can embed one into the other, for your specific case you can embed **Display** into **Loader** using a Panel in **Loader** to reload **Display** as you need.

Something like this:

```
Panel container = new Panel();
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
container.add(secondApplet); //Display Applet
add(container):

secondApplet.init();
secondApplet.start();

button.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: It's almost same than in @R.J answer, but I meant including an additional Panel in Loader Applet, so You can control Display Applet as you need from Loader Applet, it also give you possibility to include additional functionality, even hiding Loader's components that you want not visualize.

I don't think you can destroy Loader Applet using this approach, due Loader Applet is creating and containing the Display Applet instance.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many things wrong with the applets it is hard to know where to begin.  But let us concentrate 1st on a more sensible strategy to cause the change beteween one view and another.

1. Instead of having two applets, have two panels that are swapped in a `CardLayout`
2. Instead of having both applets in one page, call `getAppletContext().showDocument(secondAppletURL);`.  Presumably `secondAppletURL` is different to the URL of the page that hosts the first applet.

OK - the problems with the first applet:

1. Don't try to set the size of an applet.  It is set by the HTML.
2. All the methods calls in the `start()` method should be moved to the `init()` method, since the `start()` method might be called repeatedly.  Then there is no reason to override `start()` at all.
3. Don't mix Swing (e.g. `JApplet`) & AWT (e.g. `Button`) components without good cause.  In this case, use `JButton` instead of `Button`.
4. As a stylistic point, it is typically better to create an anonymous inner `ActionListener` than implement it on the parent class.
5. Overriding `paint()` with an empty implementation is not a good idea.  The original `paint()` draws the applet and components, so now it would do nothing.
6. The methods in the `actionPerformed()` are equally nonsensical.  An applet does not get included into the `AppletContext` until after `init()` & `start()` have been called, which would mean that calling those methods explicitly causes them to be invoked a second time.  While the `start()` method is meant to be called multiple times, the `init()` method should only be called once.

2nd Applet.

1. Ditto point 1. re the 1st applet.
2. The overridden `paint()` method ..would paint the BG color (or the FG color - not sure) but nothing else.  Again, don't override it.

Comment: So basically the right approach would be replacing the panel of one applet from another Panel ??

Comment: If that had read *"replacing the panel of one applet **with** another Panel ??"* I might have said 'yes'.  As it is, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh yes.. I meant the same !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to load another applet. See if it works.

```
Class applet2 = Class.forName("Applet2");
Applet appletToLoad = (Applet)applet2.newInstance();
appletToLoad.setStub(this);
setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
add(appletToLoad);
appletToLoad.init();
appletToLoad.start();
```

Comment: Yeah, It worked !!
But both the classes are running in the same Applet !!
How to destroy the Loader Applet ??